# Patent for more than one product

Tags: multipal

Can anyone tell me if there is a multiple Patent for more than one product but in the same field of work?

Comment: What do you mean? Are you asking if you can file for multiple patents regarding the same product?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're talking about the US, patents are essentially unrelated to products. A patent might cover one product or a hundred, and a product may reflect one patent or a hundred -- and, in fact, a patent might not cover any product at all, and a product may not reflect any patent at all.

Answer (score 0):

A single patent can (and does) have multiple claims, but it sounds like what you'd want is just multiple patents. In some cases, an examiner will instruct you to separate out your claims (or a claim, mostly likely if an inexperienced person drafts the application) into multiple patent applications.

Ultimately, it just depends on what sort of coverage you want, and how diverse the "products" are. But a patent is on an invention, so the different aspects would have to be part of the same invention. No surprise, your best bet is probably to meet with a patent professional to decide which aspects are worth patenting, and how you might be able to handle that in an affordable way (assuming that's why you'd want to fit it all into one).

Answer (score 0):

Basically, a single patent is granted to one products. But as what Matthew said, you can have multiple claims in one patent. Claims are important in patent application, it is where you put the details on the extent of protection you want for your patents. Each claim in examined individually if it is valid or invalid.